# Cloudformation Cloudwatch Template

Tags: amazon-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a bunch of existing servers in EC2. Future servers are created with Cloudformation with Cloudwatch integration. However, I need to setup Cloudwatch for servers that weren't created with Cloudformation.

I have been asked to create a Cloudwatch Cloudformation stack. Is it possible to just create alarms in Cloudformation? If so, how do I specify which servers to monitor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudWatch on EC2 [is enabled with the EC2 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-MonitorInstances.html).  Since you have already created the instances outside CloudFormation, CloudFormation cannot modify them.  You can create Alarms with CloudFormation, but you cannot enable monitoring on the instances.  If you have monitoring enabled, you can reference the instances by specifying the ["Dimensions" property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-dimension.html) in the template.